# How to resolve issue with angular LocalStorageModule failing with $injector:modulerr message after ngmin

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, mean-stack

I went through the [yeoman tutorial](http://yeoman.io/codelab.html) and when I execute `grunt serve` the resulting app works fine. However it fails when I execute `grunt serve:dist`. The error message is:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module mytodoApp due to: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: a
```

In my app.js file if I comment out the call to configure (which sets the prefix) then the issue goes away:

```
angular.module('mytodoApp', ['LocalStorageModule', 'ngCookies', 'ngResource', 'ngSanitize', 'ngRoute', 'ui.sortable'])
.config(['localStorageServiceProvider', function (localStorageServiceProvider) {
    localStorageServiceProvider.setPrefix('ls');
}])
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wrapping my app.js file as follows resolved the issue:

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('mytodoApp', ['LocalStorageModule','ngCookies','ngResource','ngSanitize','ngRoute','ui.sortable']);
    app.config(['localStorageServiceProvider', function (localStorageServiceProvider) {
        localStorageServiceProvider.setPrefix('ls');
    }]);
    app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
                controller: 'MainCtrl'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
    });
}.call(this));
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. As suggested by Eddie, I ended up combining the two .config sections like so:

```
.config(function ($routeProvider, localStorageServiceProvider) {
    localStorageServiceProvider.setPrefix('ls');

    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
        controller: 'AboutCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the second .config() block in ngMin safe code:

```
angular.module('mytodoApp', ['LocalStorageModule', 'ngCookies', 'ngResource', 'ngSanitize', 'ngRoute', 'ui.sortable'])
.config(['localStorageServiceProvider', function (localStorageServiceProvider) {
    localStorageServiceProvider.setPrefix('ls');
}])
.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
}]);
```

Or combine the two blocks.

Comment: Well, I think the second block is not the issue.  If I comment out the 1st config block (which is already allegedly ngMin safe) it works fine  but alas no prefix. Regardless wrapping it as in my answer above fixed it.